# Proving that any irreducible complex representation of an abelian group is 1-dimensional.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, modules, representation-theory

I want to prove that any irreducible complex representation of an abelian group is 1-dimensional. I will use the following:

> **Definition 1**: A nonzero $G$ module $V$ is reducible if it has a basis in which every $g\in G$ is assigned a block matrix of the form
> $$
> X(g)=\begin{bmatrix} A(g)&B(g)\\ 
> 0 & C(g)\end{bmatrix},
> $$
> where $A(g)$ is square and of the same size for each $g$ and $0$ is a nonempty zero matrix.

> **Proposition 2:** Let $X$ be an irreducible matrix representation of $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Then the only matrices $T$ that commute with $X(g)$ for all $g\in G$ are those of the form $T=cI$, with $c\in \mathbb{C}$ and $I$ the identity.

**Proof**: Let $X$ be an irreducible complex representation of an abelian group $G$. Then for arbitrary $g,h\in G$, we have:
$$\tag{1}
X(g)X(h)=X(gh)=X(hg)=X(h)X(g),
$$
which shows that $X(h)$ commutes with $X(g)$. Since this is true for any $g$, Proposition 2 tells us that $X(h)$ is diagonal. Since $h$ was arbitrary, Definition 1 tells us that $X$ is reducible unless $\dim{X}=1$. But we assumed that $X$ was irreducible, so we must have $\dim{X}=1$. Is this conclusion correct?

**Edit**: I was asked to specify what I am unsure about in my proof. Basically, it is just the last part. I know equation $(1)$ is correct, because $G$ is abelian. So I would like to confirm that I am using definition 1 and proposition 2 correctly in my conclusion that $\dim{X}=1$.

Comment: [This question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/), linked from the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki, indicates that questions which are of the form "Here's my proof, what's wrong with it?" are generally not a good fit for this site.  The point of the [tag:solution-verification] tag is to get help with *specific* details in an argument.  If you cannot point to a particular step of the argument that you think might be incorrect, then you are essentially asking the community here to grade your homework.  Such questions are not generally a good fit for the site.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, I edited the question. As written in the edit, it is the very last part  where I use definition 1 and proposition 2 in conjunction to say that $\dim{X}=1$ that I want to make sure is correct..

Comment: The question does not have an answer, because I want to specifically know if _my_ solution is correct.

Comment: It's fine but you could certainly spell out in more detail the precise way you are using Definition 1.